# Logic/Algorithm - Storing Chosen Items in a List as Ints - And undoing this again?

Tags: algorithm, logic, calculation

I've seen someone's code and they've got a list of items and they're saving the chosen item by an int.
These are the same ints that represent bits, e.g.
1,2,4,8,16,32,64,etc.

I understand the concept of this, because you can just get one final value, and work out exactly what has been chosen, as every variation will still have a unique total.

My question is, what would be the calculation to undo the total into the separate ints again? (So that I can work out the chosen objects)

I can't conceptualise it.
This looks like it would be a lot more memory efficient for applications, rather than storing lists of chosen objects etc.

Could anyone help me get the chosen items back out of the final number?

(I did try a google search, but I wasn't sure quite how to word it so I didn't find much!)

Thanks

Comment: That method would only work for 32 items in a 32 bit int, or 64 in a 64 bit int. To know the chosen items, you just need to check if the number has a 1 in the ith place of its binary representation. Depends on the language, but its usually done as if (num && (1 << i))

Comment: Thanks! I only have 7 items (weekdays) and I found java bitwise operators. I got it working, slightly different to your answer!

Comment: Its the same thing, you just used a name for 1 << 0, 1 << 2, 1 << 3 and so on. The == mondayBit parts are unnecesary, != 0 would suffice

Comment: Ah that's a good point. I'll implement that. Thanks very much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Found out. Java bitwise operators! The & (in Java) or 'and' (in Kotlin) compares two numbers. If they both have a 1 in the same place bitwise, then the result will also have a 1 in the same bit place.

So I was able to compare my total int to the ints representing each day.

So my code was so much simpler than I thought it would be!

```
val mondayIncluded = (event.repeatDays and mondayBit) != 0
val tuesdayIncluded = (event.repeatDays and tuesdayBit) != 0
val wednesdayIncluded = (event.repeatDays and wednesdayBit) != 0
val thursdayIncluded = (event.repeatDays and thursdayBit) != 0
val fridayIncluded = (event.repeatDays and fridayBit) != 0
val saturdayIncluded = (event.repeatDays and saturdayBit) != 0
val sundayIncluded = (event.repeatDays and sundayBit) != 0
```

So basically it is saying, if the bit for 4 is on for the total int, and the bit is on for wednesday, then the result will also have the bit on for wednesday, so I know it has been selected. (Difficult to explain!)

Answer (score 0):

let's say that a chosen item is represented by 1, and a not chosen item is represented by 0. If you have an array of, let's say, 7 elements, then '1000001' could mean that the first and the last elements in the list were selected, while all the other elements were not. Since for every element in the list there are only two values, selected/not selected, then, for every position in the resulting string, there are only two possible values - 0 and 1. This means you basically obtained a number in base  2, which, for practical purposes, can be converted to base 10. '1000001' is equal to 65 in base 10.

The reverse operation is the conversion from base 10 to base 2. Turning 65 back into '1000001' gives a clear hint which elements were selected and which were not.

please google about conversion from base 10 to base 2 and viceversa, to find exactly how the conversion takes place